# Better way to express an array property

Tags: c#, arrays, properties

Consider the array property:

```
private object m_value;
public string[,] StringArray 
{
    get { return ValueToStrings(m_value); }
    set { m_value = StringsToValue(value); } 
}
```

You will see that this is incredibly wrong when you try to use the property like this:

```
StringArray[0, 0] = "2";
MessageBox.Show(StringArray[0, 0]);
```

Because the array is computed each time it is accessed, the assignment is only affecting a very transient piece of data and you get a fresh unchanged value when you access StringArray[0, 0] again.

What would be a better design to make the property look like an array/matrix but actually affect underlying data when a single element is set?

Comment: Note, this is not actually being misused in the real code, but I'm doing cleanup and testing and found this potential maintenance issue.

Comment: What is the type of the object you initialise `m_value` with? (Presumably the return type of `StringsToValue`)

Comment: If you're ignoring operations performed on the array in `ValueToStrings` then why even have a setter?  It seems like the intention was to return a new array each time.  If it is not... well, then don't create a new array.

Comment: Yes, the setter is entirely unnecessary in the real code, but removing it does not solve the issue, it does not make the array elements read-only.

Comment: m_value is a polymorphic data structure.  The nature of the conversion is not important to the question, it is an internal detail.

Answer (score 0):

write your own array class, containing an indexer accessor and pass it a Get/Set delegate that updates the internal m_value, and does not store its own copy of m_value (in fact it stores nothing). Make your existing public accessor return the instance of your array class and not generate an array dynamically.

Comment: Reasonable.  I've considered some sort of encapsulated class to handle both the array and the value.